# Trying to use a Tikz Header and include multiple lines of different text sizes in the same header

Tags: header-footer, tikz-styles

See the code below - I have a Tikz package that I've replicated to have two lines of different sizes. The problem is now that my Subheader appears below my Header, and I'm struggling to get them flipped. Ideally I want the smaller text below the larger text, and in the same Tikz entry so the Header includes the Subheader

(See screenshot of how it's appearing now, subheader above header)

```
% Header %

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2.5cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{65pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont #2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}

%SubHeader%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\subheader}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.8cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (line) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\color{header}%
      {\bodyfont #1}{\bodyfont #2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of how the Header is coming out now - note the subheader appears above the header]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We can only eventually comment your `tikzpicture`, for all others wee need to see context, how it is used. This means, that you need to provide small complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce  your problem: at least one complete page, where is your picture )used as page header?)

Comment: You also in your code fragment use commands and nodes anchor, which are unknown to us. Please, provide MWE.

Comment: You may find useful: `\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm,
   box/.style = {fill=black!80, font=\sffamily, text=white,
                 minimum height=#1, minimum width=150mm, align=center}
                        ]
\node [box=21mm] (h1)
        {Phone number - Email - Website ULR\\[2ex] 
         \fontsize{40pt}{65pt}\selectfont%
         First Name \textbf{Last Name}};
\node [box=7mm, below=of h1] (h2) {some text 1 some text 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko it is used just as a page header, yes - working on getting a MWE I can share here. This code looks like it would be useful, but when I applied it it stripped the formatting from a large part of the document

Comment: This part is where I'm having trouble, all I need is to figure out the other anchor= value to get this to be the second line of text: 

```\node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=0.8cm] (box) at (current page.north){};```

Comment: ```\usetikzlibrary{positioning}\newcommand{\headerwithsubheader}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2.5cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{65pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont #2}
    };
    \node [below=name, center] (subheader) {%
      \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\color{header}\position{center}%
      {\bodyfont #3}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}```

Comment: *Along with the tikz package, the above worked to get the Subheader below the Header - but it was pulled left off the page.

Adding \begin{center} and then \end{center} to the main.tex was enough to override and center the subheader though!

Comment: You may understand your explanation, BU unfortunately I not. So please again, provide complete small at least two page long document (with dummy text, for example generated by  `lipsum` package` ,which we van test as it is. Also explain, if this is only on the first document list or it is on all apges, How you like to insert its contents for example, define them in document preamble. Help us to help you.